# Why do we define things in terms of differential equations instead of directly in functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the 1 dimensional heat equation (which is a differential equation) - this tells you the rate at which temperature changes across the rod at different times (relative to some initial conditions):

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

The solution this equation is the following:

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \exp\left(-\alpha \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2 t\right)$$

Although the solution looks more complicated, (for me at least) its easier to understand. The solution tells us directly the temperature of the rod at any position at any time (given some initial conditions).

**My Question:** In our math lectures/classes, we always start with the differential equation and then learn how to solve this. That is, we first define the differential equation and then derive its solution. The solution to this differential equation always seem to be of prime importance as the solution can be directly applied in many real world situations.

Thus, the obvious question: **If we are so interested in the solution of the differential equation - why don't we start by directly defining an equation that we believe directly describes the temperature of the rod at some point/time (relative to the initial conditions)?** Why go through all the trouble of defining the differential equation only to then figure out how to solve it ... and eventually end up with the solution? Why not directly define the solution, instead of defining a differential equation and then solving it .... when we are primarily interested only in the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: It is easier to describe how something you are observing is changing than to try to describe its status at every instant. We *need* the differential equation to discover the function. If writing out the function from scratch were easy, we wouldn't need to do differential equations. Think about springs. What is easier: to say exactly how long the spring will be at any given time, or to say "if the spring is elongated then it will tend to shrink proportionally to how much it is elongated, and if it is compressed it will tend to expand, proportionally"?

Comment: Suppose someone just writes down the solution for you. Why should you believe it?

Comment: Okay, now do it for a square or a disk. Where do you think those equations come from?

Comment: In addition to other reasons mentioned here, the differential equation is just far more general and fundamental. The heat equation is just a one-liner and describes the behavior of a function at any point and instant. While you wrote down a very specific edge-case solution to the heat equation (one-dimensional line with unspecified boundary conditions), can you also write down its solution in any number of dimensions, on any manifold and with any kind of boundary conditions? Can you do the same thing for any other differential equation as well?

Comment: Another reason the differential equation is more fundamental is that it may contain unspecified functions depending on different variables.  As a simple example in the equation F=ma, the force can be many different functions of position, velocity, time, or even other factors depending on the situation.

Comment: If you are interested in a different perspective, check out [*Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics (SICM)*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262028967/structure-and-interpretation-of-classical-mechanics/). *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP)* is one of the most famous Computer Science textbooks. It uses (a subset of) the Scheme programming language to teach practically all of CS. One of the authors happens to be a physicist by training and they realized that the same approach could be used for physics. SICM describes the "laws of mechanics" not in mathematical

Comment: … language but in computer language. I like to say that computers are much dumber than humans, so if you can write something down in a way that a computer can understand it, then a human definitely can, too. Computer programs are unambiguous and precise, since computers aren't capable of "reading between the lines", guessing based on context, etc. As an added advantage, the way the definitions are expressed in the book, they are also executable as simulations. The book is freely available: https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/9579/sicm_edition_2.zip/book.html

Comment: Could you elaborate on this: "*Why not directly define the solution...?*"  Are you saying we can define the 1 dimensional heat equation to be anything we want?  We define (rather than discover) how the physical world actually works?

Comment: *Why go through all the trouble of defining the differential equations...* Trouble? What trouble? The differential equations fall in our laps with ease by applying the laws of physics which govern a given physical situation.

Answer (score 15):

Roughly speaking, what we take to be the "laws of physics" are expressed as differential equations. So to find out how the values of physical measurements evolve in time we solve those differential equations.

The classic (first?) instance of this paradigm is Newton's
$$
F = ma .
$$
Knowing the acceleration you integrate twice to find the position. With this "law" you can derive what Galileo discovered about falling bodies and what Kepler discovered about elliptical orbits. The differential equation provides the "why" that unifies the observations.

Comment: As a lowly physicist, I know that this is _usually_ true (with some obvious pedantic exceptions perhaps worth mentioning like hysteresis and delay differential equations – some systems, like magnets, depend on the past a while ago to determine the future). Arguably though the more interesting question is "why do the laws of physics express themselves as differential equations" and that is a _whole_ other kettle of fish.

Answer (score 11):

You're basically trying to put the **cart before the horse**.

If you have no idea about what the temperature of the rod at any position at any time is supposed to be. Would you ever guess the complicated solution in your answer? **No**.

However, thinking about changes might give you more insight and an often much easier relation.

Consider free-fall with friction. Now what assumptions can you make?

First of all, the acceleration is constant and pointing downwards:

$$\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2} = -g \vec{e}_z$$

Second, from real life you might now that the faster you move (i.e. the higher your velocity), the more wind resistance there is. A priori there is no reason to assume a linear relationship, but we're building a model here so we might just as well start with an easy one.

Clearly the wind-resistance is always moving against you, that is against your velocity vector. Add this to the differential equation

$$\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2} = -g \vec{e}_z - \alpha \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$$

If you learn to read differential equations this way, it's actually quite intuitive. Solutions might not always be obvious or [elude us for quite some long time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness). But that doesn't change that they perfectly describe the behaviour of a system.

Going back to your heat equation:

$$\frac{du}{dt} = \alpha \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}$$

The left site is easy, it just tells you how the temperature changes w.r.t. time. The right side is explained very well in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20724/131172)
In essence it just means, if the temperature is higher than its surroundings, it will drop, and if it is lower, it will rise. Make sure you really understand, what the laplacian (second derivative w.r.t. position) means.

Answer (score 3):

The two formulae you've written say the same thing but have different deep meaning. I'll take a simpler differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -g \tag{1}\label{1}$$

This quite concisely describes the variation of a mass's vertical position while in free fall, ignoring friction. We can write that differently:

$$y(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + v_0t + y_0 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Although $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ are fundamentally equivalent, the way they are written present information differently.
$\eqref{1}$ tells us that the second derivative of the position is $-g$, and we call that second derivative the acceleration.

Mentally, we are used to a model of "position varying with a speed" and "speed varying with an acceleration", and anybody that's ever been in a car or on a bike understands what acceleration means relative to position. If the acceleration is null, then the speed doesn't vary, and the mass will stay in a constant linear motion.

On the other hand, deducing that fact ("object is now in a constant motion") is not immediate from seeing this variation of $\eqref{2}$:

$$y(t) = v_0t + y_0 \tag{3}\label{3}$$

From a numerical standpoint, $\eqref{2}$ is obviously more useful than $\eqref{1}$ since we can "just evaluate it" and compute values and plot graphs. Solving equations is a more difficult task for a computer than substituting values in a formula.

> why don't we start by directly defining an equation that we believe directly describes the temperature of the rod at some point/time (relative to the initial conditions)?

The equation that directly describes the value is a obtained by solving the differential equation. Why do we start from a differential equation? When we observe something in nature, it's easier to notice that something is evolving linearly (or quadratically, etc.) relative to time than to guess a correct formula out of the blue.

Why, then, do we teach the differential equation instead of directly giving the solution? Because understanding a process becomes much easier the fewer assumptions you start with, and a short differential equation will usually give a better mental model than a complex solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution for the rod is an approximation based on the idea that the rod is infinitely thin - or at least significantly thinner than it is long. You are welcome to memorize this solution, but it won't help the case where the pizza (a disc) or the turkey (a sphere) is being heated in an oven. It won't help with the flow of heat from the center of the earth to the crust through non-homogenous media. It won't help with keeping your beer cold in your mug, and it won't help you design your radiator.

The differential equation is a pretty good tool because it applies to an infinite number of boundary conditions each with its own solution. Which is to say ... the solution you've provided is correct for significantly less than 1% of systems.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer sufficiently focus on the your particular case of your question about differential equations. I would like to complement a more general view. In mathematics and computer science we often abstractly define things by stating their desired properties.
This principle is so general that many names have emerged for this one and the same principle applied to different areas. Here are some examples:

- (applied mathematics): differential equation - solution
- (logic) axioms - theory
- (logic) theorem - proof
- (type theory) type - inhabitant
- (philosophy) postulates - reality
- (programming) interface/abstract class - implementing class

In every case across these fields, we are typically more interested in the abstractum (the thing written left to `-`) because it is typically easier to deal/reason with and easier to integrate with others parts of the field's theories, concepts, and ontologies.
Still, the concretum in every case plays a vital role in establishing the very existence of the abstractum to begin with. And particularly in applied situations (numerics or programming), the concretum is typically the only entity that can be computed with.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single answer. the reasons are multiples. there just happen to be more in writing in differential forms than the functionals.
Some examples of reasons why we might write in differential forms:

- They can be less overwhelming to write and to read (syntatic sugar, just like programming languages) (your equation is a perfect example of this)
- Sometimes its because integrals are more intuitive (eg. F=ma) its intuitevly easier to imagine force+acceleration than to imagine work+velocity or power+position. (not only to the reader but also to the person who found it)
- One of the biggest reason might be that geometry is much MUCH intuitive with derivatives (take an example arc length formula vs Differential Form)
- Historical reasons.
- etc...

That doesn't mean you won't find direct functions though. They can be popular too.